# Status bar adding extra padding React-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, statusbar

I tried adding status bar to the app and it is adding extra padding on React-Navigation Header

**status bar code**

```
const STATUSBAR_HEIGHT = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 30 : StatusBar.currentHeight;
const NotificationBar = ({ backgroundColor, ...props }) => ({
  ...(Platform.OS == 'ios' ? (
    <View style={{ backgroundColor, height: 30 }}>
      <StatusBar translucent backgroundColor={backgroundColor} {...props} />
    </View>
  ) : (
    <StatusBar translucent backgroundColor={backgroundColor} {...props} />
  )),
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  statusBar: {
    height: STATUSBAR_HEIGHT,
  },
});
```

**app.js**

```
 <Provider store={store}>
      <NotificationBar
        backgroundColor={Colors.SAPrimaryx}
        barStyle="light-content"
      />
      <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
        <RootRouter />
      </PersistGate>
 </Provider>
```

How do i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding a status bar i just changed the color of the content of the status bar

```
  <Provider store={store}>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
      <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
        <RootRouter />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't set `View` height, it will add extra height. You can follow by this docs 
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/status-bar.html